# MySQL CASE WHEN END in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Currently I am working on Codeigniter projected related to stores management. In model I used the following function to get the purchase & issues summary for the view through controller.

## Function

```
function issueDetailReport($id,$start,$end){
        $this->db->select('*, store_update_stock_details.item,
        CASE 
        WHEN store_update_stock.order_status = "purchase" THEN tbl_supplier.supplier_name
        WHEN store_update_stock.order_status = "issue" THEN store_officer.officer_name 
        END AS supplier');
        $this->db->from('store_update_stock');
        $this->db->join('store_update_stock_details','store_update_stock.update_stock_id=store_update_stock_details.update_stock_id');
        $this->db->join('store_officer','store_update_stock.supplier=store_officer.officer_id');
        $this->db->join('tbl_supplier','store_update_stock.supplier=tbl_supplier.supplier_id');
        $this->db->join('store_item','store_update_stock_details.item=store_item.item_id');
        $this->db->where("store_update_stock.status='1' and store_item.item_id=$id");
        //$this->db->where('store_update_stock.update_stock_id in (select update_stock_id from store_update_stock) ');
        if($start!=NULL && $end!=NULL)
        $this->db->where("store_update_stock.billed_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'");
        $this->db->order_by('store_update_stock.purchased_date','DESC');
        $q=$this->db->get();
        if($q->num_rows()>0){
            return $q->result();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

02) All are working fine. But the case constructor fires the following error

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`order_status = "issue" THEN store_officer`.`officer_name END` AS `supplier` FR' at line 1

03) I tried to solve the issue. But did't get the desired output. I can't find the error & what may be wrong. Can anyone help me ?

## Supplier Table

```
+-------------+---------------+
| supplier_id | supplier_name |
+-------------+---------------+
|         500 | ABC           |
|         501 | DEF           |
|         502 | GHI           |
|         503 | JKL           |
+-------------+---------------+
```

## officer Table

```
+------------+--------------+
| officer_id | officer_name |
+------------+--------------+
|       1000 | Danial       |
|       1001 | Jhon         |
|       1002 | William      |
|       1003 | Patrick      |
|       1004 | Salman       |
+------------+--------------+
```

## Output

```
+------+--------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+
| item | supplier / officer_name  |   start    |    end     | order_status |
+------+--------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+
| A4   | ABC                      | 2018-11-01 | 2018-11-01 | purchase     |
| A5   | DEF                      | 2018-11-01 | 2018-11-01 | purchase     |
| A3   | Danial                   | 2018-11-02 | 2018-11-02 | issue        |
| B5   | Jhon                     | 2018-11-05 | 2018-11-05 | issue        |
+------+--------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Can you output the generated query?  Your function seem to be ok.

Comment: Try to change case statement to `CASE  store_update_stock.order_status
        WHEN "purchase" THEN tbl_supplier.supplier_name
        WHEN "issue" THEN store_officer.officer_name 
        END AS supplier`

Comment: @Daniel. My output as same as the edit

Comment: Move the `*` from before the `CASE` statement to after the `END AS` and it'll work... This is a MySQL syntax error, not attributable to CI

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
$this->db->select('*, store_update_stock_details.item,
    CASE 
    WHEN store_update_stock.order_status = "purchase" THEN tbl_supplier.supplier_name
    WHEN store_update_stock.order_status = "issue" THEN store_officer.officer_name 
    END AS supplier');
```

To:

```
$this->db->select('store_update_stock_details.item,
    CASE 
    WHEN store_update_stock.order_status = "purchase" THEN tbl_supplier.supplier_name
    WHEN store_update_stock.order_status = "issue" THEN store_officer.officer_name 
    END AS supplier, *');
```

MySQL doesn't like stuff in the select statements after *'s and many times it'll refuse to work